# Slow initial connections. Ping/Traceroute significant start up time, no packet loss

Tags: networking, dns, nixos

I am running NixOS, and ever since I installed it a few days ago I've been noticing a significant delay when initially connecting to websites.
Before installing it I never observed such an issue, and nothing whatsoever has physically changed on my network setup (wired connection, same computer, same router, same router settings).

However, I notice something that seems quite strange to me. When I try to run a simple ping command (or traceroute) there is *no text whatsoever* printed to the screen for a full 5-10 seconds. Not even the initial "PING [website]" message. Despite the huge delay before the pings start there is 0% packet loss and once it starts pings come in at regular intervals with good latency.
Traceroute does the exact same thing with *no text* at all, not even the initial "traceroute to [website]" message for quite some time (even if I use -n to avoid reverse lookup)

I tried changing my DNS servers to google's (8.8.8.8, and 8.8.4.4) but there is no improvement.
I don't think it's a DNS issue, as other machines on the same network are not experiencing this problem.

Pinging my router always seems to work perfectly fine without any delays. I'm at a complete loss as to where to even look next.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being that my /etc/resolv.conf only had my router listed as the nameserver. Adding other DNS servers such as google's fixed the issue.
*(I thought changing it in the router was good enough and wasn't aware that it could be set on my system)*

Note that in NixOS this can be set by adding **networking.nameservers** to the configuration.nix file.

Comment: The router shouldn't be so extremely slow to answer DNS. There's something wrong about that.  I suspect it might choke on EDNS, even though it has been standardized for so long.  That might be disabled by `networking.dnsExtensionMechanism = false`, but using a better server like you did seems better to me.